Use Angluar-Cli App as npm package with generate build
I have angular 17 app, when i run npm run build it generate the dist/browser folder having main.js, polyfills.js and index.html and some style.css files, i want to deploy the generated dist/browser folder as npm package, so that once i install the npm package with the following only i can use the complete generate angular app.
but currently the issues is i deployed the dist/browser folder but its needs types and i am not aware of it.
I tried adding typings/.d.ts but nothing works or i might be adding it at wrong place. I request help on how can use use angular-cli generate project as npm package.
